# keeping the original values in a data frame based on a condition

Tags: r, if-statement

Im trying to filter/change the value in a data frame based on a set of conditions.

```
 a <- c(18, 12, 15, 8, 4, 2, 9, 1)
 b <- 14

 c = a - b 
  [1]   4  -2   1  -6 -10 -12  -5 -13
```

Is it possible that where the output is negative, it takes the  original number?

For example

18 - 14 = 4 (positive so its OK)

12 - 14 = -2 (negative so it should just stick with the 12)

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `ifelse` statement?

```
vec <- a - b
ifelse(vec < 0, a, vec)
#[1]  4 12  1  8  4  2  9  1
```

Or with direct assignment without using `ifelse`.

```
vec <- a - b
vec[vec < 0] <- a[vec < 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though Ronak has provided very good answer, just to add, you may also use `replace`

like this

```
replace(c, c<0, a[c<0])
[1]  4 12  1  8  4  2  9  1
```

- first argument of `replace` is a vector whose values are to be replaced
- second is indices where the values are to be replaced
- third and last is vector of replacement values.